# how to avoid repetitive symbol from file in Linux shell script and reformat

Tags: shell

I have to format below output in proper format and avoid repetitive string occurrence in shell script as I got below output after using paste command  ?

```
$ paste file1 file2
TRADE_DATE:12 Jul 2023   TRADE_DATE:13 Jul 2023
Symbol: AMAZON           Symbol: AMAZON
Price: 100.50           Price: 100.30
Symbol: TESLA       Symbol: TESLA
Price: 60.80        Price: 60.50
```

Desired output like :

```
TRADE_DATE     Symbol      Price
12 Jul 2023    AMAZON      100.50
12 Jul 2023    TESLA       60.80
13 Jul 2023    AMAZON      100.30
13 Jul 2023    TESLA       60.50
```

Comment: I'd probably write a program, in your choice of shell or awk, to store already-seen items in a dictionary or associative array and suppress reprinting.

Comment: Do you have a specific technical problem that prevents you from doing this yourself? For what it's worth, we have a lot of examples already in our knowledgebase of folks using awk to implement `uniq` without `sort`. (Note that to be on-topic here, a Stack Overflow question should be about a technical problem you encountered while implementing a program yourself).

Comment: (btw, is there a reason to use the `paste` command here at all, as opposed to processing your input files individually?)

Comment: Thanks a lot Charles , will try out but is there not any other way to get it done in one command line ? Yes as I have to use paste command only to get append output of 2 files in single file and email it

Comment: Anything can be "one command line"; you can fit as many lines of code into one command as you want; it's much better to focus on readable, maintainable code than how many lines it is.

Comment: I _did_ add an answer, but please next time try to narrow the question on the place you got stuck building something yourself, instead of just asking for a program written to spec.

Answer (score 0):

A [BashFAQ #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) `while read` loop lets you iterate over lines of input. Using `IFS` lets you split those lines into fields, so you can ignore headers.

```
extract() {
  local file IFS=': '       # so we don't pollute global variable scope
  printf '%s\t%s\t%s\n' "TRADE_DATE" "SYMBOL" "PRICE"  # print header
  for file; do              # "$@" is the default thing to iterate over
    {                       # grouping to scope input redirection
      read -r _ trade_date  # read everything before IFS into _
      while read -r _ symbol && read -r _ price; do
        printf '%s\t%s\t%s\n' "$trade_date" "$symbol" "$price"
      done
    } <"$file"
  done
}
```

...used as:

```
extract file1 file2
```